# Are free stock imagery usable in books and websites?

Tags: graphics, license, vector-graphics, creative-commons

I see a lot of "free" stock imagery and vector graphics available on the Internet, but when I recommend such things for use on publications or websites, my clients ask me for printable licenses or any GPL/CreativeCommons declaration, but I find none on the websites themselves.

Do you have any idea whether such "free" graphics are usable for such media? Do I have to declare their source in publications or websites, if I use them outright?

- [stock.exchange](http://www.sxc.hu/) - photos
- [vecteezy](http://www.vecteezy.com/) - vector art

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no one answer fits all. Read the small print on the websites themselves and if you are unsure, try contacting the site owner.

From your post -

Stock Exchange - http://www.sxc.hu/help/7_2 and

> You may use the Image
>
> - In digital format on websites, multimedia presentations, broadcast
>     film and video, cell phones.
> - In printed promotional materials, magazines, newspapers,
>     books, brochures, flyers, CD/DVD
>     covers, etc.
> - Along with your corporate identity on business cards,
>     letterhead, etc.
> - To decorate your home, your office or any public place.
>
> You may not use the Image
>
> - For pornographic, unlawful or other immoral purposes, for spreading
>     hate or discrimination, or to defame
>     or victimise other people, sociteties,
>     cultures.
> - To endorse products and services if it depicts a person.
> - In a way that can give a bad name to SXC or the person(s) depicted
>     on the Image.
> - As part of a trademark, service mark or logo.
> - SELLING AND REDISTRIBUTION OF THE IMAGE (INDIVIDUALLY OR ALONG WITH
>     OTHER IMAGES) IS STRICTLY FORBIDDEN!
>     DO NOT SHARE THE IMAGE WITH OTHERS!
>
> Always ask permission from the
>   photographer if you want to use the
>   Image
>
> - In website templates that You intend to sell or distribute.
> - For creating printed reproductions that You intend to sell.
> - On "print on demand" items such as t-shirts, postcards, mouse pads,
>     mugs (e.g. on sites like Cafepress),
>     or on any similar mass produced item
>     that would contain the Image in a
>     dominant way.

Vecteezy - I cannot locate the same level of licence, but I found this page - http://www.vecteezy.com/terms

Answer (score 2):

Both Vecteezy

> Vecteezy will not be held responsible
>   for the uses of any graphics...contact
>   the creators of the files you use.

and Stock Exchange

> in some cases you may need to notify
>   the artists about using the images and
>   sometimes you need to give credit to
>   them

sidestep any legal responsibilities by referring you to deal with each artist and any peculiar licensing tendencies they may have.  I guess the short answer is maybe, but you'll have to contact each artist.

iStockPhoto is so much better about this: you only deal with them and the terms of use are clear.  The Standard licensing covers a lot of ground for normal usage, but if you happen to need Extended it can cost $100+ per artwork.

Answer (score 0):

(I am not a lawyer). The art from these sites are licensed under the terms that are posted on the sites. I know stock.exchange has the terms listed on the page based on the requirements of the creator. For the others look around.

I looked at vecteezy and it looks like its listed on each page.